# Converting a byte array to PNG/JPG

Tags: c#, png, jpeg

I am currently working on an application that requires high-performance conversion of an unpadded byte array to either a PNG or JPEG. The image format doesn't matter, just as long as it's fast.

I have tried the .NET libraries and the performance is very bad. Can anyone recommend a good freeware library for this?

EDIT: the byte[] is an 8bit grayscale bitmap

Comment: It's not clear what you mean - what is this byte array to start with? Could you give more details?

Comment: Your question isn't entirely clear. What does the `byte[]` represent? Is it the content of the actual image? Is it an uncompressed Bitmap that you want to save as JPG / PNG?

Comment: The question is just request for library recommendation. If you feel that it needs to be re-opened please edit the question so it does not look like recommendation request. Even then probably duplicate  of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15270844/how-can-i-convert-byte-to-bitmapimage/15272528

Answer (score 99, accepted):

You should be able to do something like this:

```
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;

byte[] bitmap = GetYourImage();

using(Image image = Image.FromStream(new MemoryStream(bitmap)))
{
    image.Save("output.jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);  // Or Png
}
```

Look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9t4syfhh.aspx) for more info.

Hopefully this helps.

Comment: +1...pretty much the Usual Way of doing it. Depending on the user's requirements, though, no need to save it to the files system.

Comment: Perfect. I love it! This was _exactly_ what I was looking for.

Comment: Hi, I'm trying similar thing to convert raw image to jpeg butgetting *Parameter is not valid* exception. Any ideas? `byte[] bytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\Input.CR2");

                using (Image image = Image.FromStream(new MemoryStream(bytes)))
                {
                    image.Save(@"C:\output.jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg); 
                }`

Comment: Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6333681/c-sharp-parameter-is-not-valid-creating-new-bitmap. Could be that the file is too large.

Comment: Why convert to `Image` first instead of just wiring bytes directly to file so long as you know the file type and include the correct extension?

Comment: @markmnl Because the Byte array may not contain the header information needed to open the file.

Answer (score 1):

I like Imagemagick.
http://www.imagemagick.org/script/api.php

Comment: I know this is for using the programming library, but what would the command line for the tool in that case ?

Comment: @user2284570 If you are using it on the command line, then you would be working with a file and not a byte array. Assuming that your input is PNG (a PNG signature followed by chunks), then `convert input.png output.jpg` would probably work.

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems with this question:

Assuming you have a gray scale bitmap, you have two factors to consider:

1. For JPGS... what loss of quality is tolerable?
2. For pngs... what level of compression is tolerable?  (Although for most things I've seen, you don't have that much of a choice, so this choice might be negligible.)  For anybody thinking this question doesn't make sense: yes, you can change the amount of compression/number of passes attempted to compress; check out either Ifranview or some of it's plugins.

Answer those questions, and then you might be able to find your original answer.