# Turn byte[] to .jpeg and zip

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to write a method to turn the byte[] to .jpeg file and then zip these jpeg files.

I did some research but still couldnt figure it out. Thank you for your help.

## code updated

```
Using Ionic.Zip;
public static void ZipJpeg(int ID)
{
    ZipFile zip = new ZipFile();
    Dictionary<int, byte[]> photos = new Dictionary<int, byte[]>();
    photos = clientInfo_BL.GetByID(ID);
    string fileName;
    foreach(var p in photos.Values)
    {
        fileName = p.uploadDate.toString() + ".jpeg";
        using(Image image = image.FromStream(new MemoryStream(p.ImageData)))
        {
             image.Save(fileName. ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        }
        Zip.AddEntry(image); // couldnt figure out this one
    }
    zip.save()//not sure if this one is right
    return zip;
}
```

Comment: start by searching for one step then the other.

Comment: what is inside byte[]? also sure your code does not work. there is no magic.take a look at here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8946846/converting-a-byte-array-to-png-jpg also to zip files just google it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/940582/how-do-i-zip-a-file-in-c-using-no-3rd-party-apis

Comment: Thank you for your helps. The posts online about zip file I have read were mostly using the file system to zip the files, which are not what I want.  I wish to return the zip file with jpeg files to the user with out using the file system.

Answer (score 3):

since you already have your byte array, you're just one step away from converting it to jpeg!

```
using(Image image = Image.FromStream(new MemoryStream(bitmap)))
{
    image.Save("output.jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);  
}
```

[Image.FromStream()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.image.fromstream%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)