# Converting a byte array to a PNG C#?

Tags: c#, arrays, byte, png

I am trying to convert an 8 bit byte[] array, captured from a machine vision camera, into a png.

[Converting a byte array to PNG/JPG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8946846/converting-a-byte-array-to-png-jpg/8946937#8946937)
I tried following the code from this thread which deals with the same problem but I am getting an error.

This is my code:

```
  for (int i = 0; i < 1; ++i)
                    {
                        // Wait for an image and then retrieve it. A timeout of 5000 ms is used.
                        IGrabResult grabResult = camera.StreamGrabber.RetrieveResult(5000, TimeoutHandling.ThrowException);
                        using (grabResult)
                        {
                            // Image grabbed successfully?
                            if (grabResult.GrabSucceeded)
                            {
                                // Access the image data.
                                Console.WriteLine("SizeX: {0}", grabResult.Width);
                                Console.WriteLine("SizeY: {0}", grabResult.Height);
                                buffer = grabResult.PixelData as byte[];
                                Console.WriteLine("Gray value of first pixel: {0}", buffer[0]);
                                Console.WriteLine("");

                                // Display the grabbed image.
                                ImageWindow.DisplayImage(0, grabResult);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("Error: {0} {1}", grabResult.ErrorCode, grabResult.ErrorDescription);
                            }
                        }

                        using (Image image = Image.FromStream(new MemoryStream(buffer)))
                        {
                            image.Save("output.jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);  // Or Png
                        }

                        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);

                    }
```

This is my error message:

Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentException' in System.Drawing.dll
Exception: Parameter is not valid.
[image]

Comment: Can you please include the complete Stacktrace and Message? And if there is a line mentioned, mark that line in the code?

Comment: Also please clarify if it's .NET Core or .NET Framework

Comment: @DourHighArch I added my full code above. I used Image because the example I linked started with a byte[] as well.

Comment: @AlexanderGoldabin .NET Framwork, I trigger image capture from the press of a button on a GUI.

Comment: @Fildor The code is failing on this line: using (Image image = Image.FromStream(new MemoryStream(buffer))) - I know because I tried doing Console.Write() before and after that line. I added a picture of the call stack immediately before the breakpoint. Without the breakpoint the call stack is empty.

Comment: I agree with @DourHighArch, are you certain buffer is an image?

Comment: @LinkedListT Buffer is a byte array. Which is the same as the example I linked AFAIK.

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/17668083/9936356

Comment: A few strange things about that code; `using(grabResult)` will dispose `grabResult` before you save it, and you call `image.Save` if `grabResult.GrabSucceeded` is false. Try moving the `image.Save` after `buffer = grabResult.PixelData` and use your debugger to inspect `buffer`.

Comment: @DourHighArch What do you mean by false? The code is working fine (showing the image in a pop up window) and is from the camera manufacturer sample kit. I am just stuck on the last part which is saving it out to a png. I tried moving my code into the for loop under the buffer = grabResult.PixelData like you said and I got the same error.

Comment: System.Drawing.ImageConverter converter = new System.Drawing.ImageConverter();
Image img = (Image)converter.ConvertFrom(buffer);
img.Save("output.jpg", ImageFormat.Png);  // Or Png  I added this code and I am getting the same error @LinkedListT