# Printing picture box

Tags: c#, winforms

When I try to print a `PictureBox`, an `ArgumentException` is thrown (parameter is not valid).

This is the printing functions:

```
void pdGroupBox_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
{
    foreach(Control control in _GbFrm.Controls)
        DrawControls(control, e.Graphics);
}

private void DrawControls(Control control,Graphics g)
{
    var font = new Font("Arial", 10);
    var brush = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);
    var drawFormat = new StringFormat
    {
        FormatFlags = StringFormatFlags.DirectionRightToLeft
    };

    if (control is Label)
    {
        if ((string)control.Tag == "1") //Treated with 1 columns of fields.
        {
            g.DrawString(
                control.Text, font, brush,
                new Rectangle(control.Location.X - 160, control.Location.Y, control.Size.Width + 10, control.Size.Height),
                drawFormat);
        }
        if ((string)control.Tag == "2") //Treated with 2 columns of fields.
        {
            g.DrawString(
                control.Text, font, brush,
                new Rectangle(control.Location.X - 70, control.Location.Y, control.Size.Width + 10, control.Size.Height),
                drawFormat);
        }
        if ((string)control.Tag == "3") //Treated with 3 columns of fields.
        {
            g.DrawString(
                control.Text, font, brush,
                new Rectangle(control.Location.X, control.Location.Y, control.Size.Width + 10, control.Size.Height));
        }
    }
    else if (control is TextBox || control is ComboBox)
    {
        if ((string)control.Tag == "1") //Treated with 1 columns of fields.
        {
            g.DrawRectangle(
                new Pen(Color.Black, 1),
                new Rectangle(control.Location.X - 120, control.Location.Y, control.Size.Width - 40, control.Size.Height));
            g.DrawString(
                control.Text, font, brush,
                new Rectangle(control.Location.X - 120, control.Location.Y, control.Size.Width - 40, control.Size.Height), drawFormat);
        }
        if ((string)control.Tag == "2") //Treated with 2 columns of fields.
        {
            g.DrawRectangle(
                new Pen(Color.Black, 1),
                new Rectangle(control.Location.X - 30, control.Location.Y, control.Size.Width - 40, control.Size.Height));
            g.DrawString(
                control.Text, font, brush,
                new Rectangle(control.Location.X - 30, control.Location.Y, control.Size.Width - 40, control.Size.Height),
                drawFormat);
        }
        if ((string)control.Tag == "3") //Treated with 3 columns of fields.
        {
            g.DrawRectangle(
                new Pen(Color.Black, 1),
                new Rectangle(control.Location.X, control.Location.Y, control.Size.Width, control.Size.Height));
            g.DrawString(
                control.Text, font, brush,
                new Rectangle(control.Location.X, control.Location.Y, control.Size.Width, control.Size.Height), drawFormat);
        }
    }
    else if (control is PictureBox && control.Visible)
    {
        var img = ((PictureBox)control).Image;
        var bitmap = new Bitmap(img,new Size(img.Width,img.Height));
        g.DrawImage(
            bitmap,
            new Rectangle(control.Location.X, control.Location.Y, control.Size.Width, control.Size.Height));
    }
    else if (control is DateTimePicker)
    {
        g.DrawString(
            control.Text, font, brush,
            new Rectangle(control.Location.X, control.Location.Y, control.Size.Width + 10, control.Size.Height));
    }
}
```

All the printing issues work, but some times printing a `PictureBox` raises that `Exception`, so how can I solve this problem?

Comment: can you post the exception? by print you mean to the printer? or drawing on the screen?

Comment: print to printer. but the exception come from this code:
Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(img,new Size(img.Width,img.Height));
because each (img.Width,img.Height) containing (parameter is not valid)

Comment: the exception message is "Parameter is not valid."

Comment: Duplicate of: [parameter is not valid creating new bitmap](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6333681/c-sharp-parameter-is-not-valid-creating-new-bitmap)

Comment: The Bitmap class is the one class that doesn't allow you to ignore the Dispose() method.  Your program is running out of unmanaged memory.  Use the *using* statement to ensure the bitmap is disposed after drawing it.  There is otherwise very little point to creating a new bitmap, just use the Image as-is.  Use the DrawImage() overload that takes a Rectangle.

Answer (score 10):

Try this: somewhat simple:

Add the following code in the button click event:

```
PrintDocument printDocument1 = new PrintDocument();
printDocument1.PrintPage +=new PrintPageEventHandler(printDocument1_PrintPage);
printDocument1.Print();
```

Then the printDocument1_PrintPage event :

```
private void printDocument1_PrintPage(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
{
    e.Graphics.DrawImage(pic.Image, 0, 0);
}
```

where pic is the picture box..

This prints the image in the picturebox.