# Printing image displayed in WPF picture box

Tags: c#, wpf, image

I am trying to print the image that displayed in ImageBox. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14039752/printing-picture-box) solution but when I tried it I got the following error:

[image]

What am I missing?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# - Convert WPF Image.source to a System.Drawing.Bitmap](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5689674/c-sharp-convert-wpf-image-source-to-a-system-drawing-bitmap)

Answer (score 0):

The property on `imagebox` is `Image`, with an uppercase "I", not `image`.

See the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.picturebox.image(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Alson not available, In WPF there's no PictureBox, there is Image (<Image x:Name="imagebox"></Image>)

Comment: So, since `imagebox` is an `Image` in itself, why don't you write simply `DrawImage(imagebox, 0, 0)`?

Comment: I tried that and gives me (cannot convert from 'System.Windows.Controls.Image' to 'System.Drawing.Image')

Comment: @AbdulsalamElsharif you need to convert from one type to the other. Try this: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5689674/c-sharp-convert-wpf-image-source-to-a-system-drawing-bitmap](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5689674/c-sharp-convert-wpf-image-source-to-a-system-drawing-bitmap)

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [PrintDialog.PrintVisual](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.printdialog.printvisual(v=vs.110).aspx) method to print out an `Image` in WPF:

```
PrintDialog pd = new PrintDialog();
myPrintDialog.PrintVisual(imagebox, "Image");
```

Comment: I will check it