# Am I coding something that is causing some type of memory issue

Tags: c#, winforms

Am I coding something that is causing some type of memory issue

```
Metafile metFil = null;

Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(x, y);

g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
```

Comment: As an aside, you're not calling `Dispose()` on your `Graphics` objects.  `using (var g = Graphics.FromImage(...)) {}`

Comment: @EdS. or on the BitMap and it's likely the MetaFile isn't either. So lot's of unmanaged resources + no cleanup isn't great. Plus [there's this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6333681/119477)

Comment: @ConradFrix: Yep, we just don't know what the calling code looks like.  A safe bet considering the "leaked" `Graphics` objects.

Comment: Ed, what would be the correct way to code it with using/dispose?  Thanks.

Comment: You will see this error when instantiating a new Bitmap when height and width parameters aren't realistic. Run through your debugger and check these values. Also, after you've used the graphics object, you'll need to call its Dispose method. It could be that your app is running out of resources after multiple calls.

Comment: In the calling function, there is a using:  using (Graphics gt = Graphics.FromImage(bm))...   Shouldn't that dispose it?

Comment: Make sure x and y are superior to zero.

Comment: Why did you remove such a massive ammount of your post, now your question is kind of pointless, the only answer we can give you now with the current edit is "you need to dispose `bmp` and `g`".

Comment: what are the value of `x` and `y` that are failing