# CreateBitmap - Parameter is not valid 9000*9000 Image Size

Tags: asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, bitmap, bitmapimage

After create newBitmap  i m getting exception  - Parameter is not valid ,
When i want to create  9000*9000 pixel image. I need to create big resolution image. I cant able to create big Image because of this error.

[image]

My RAM is **16 GB** .My system is 64 bit.  Sometime it occurs Out of memory also. 
How to solve this issue ?

Here is my code

```
 private  Bitmap createBigImage(Bitmap layerBitmap, int newWidth, int newHeight)
 {

            Bitmap newBitmap = new Bitmap(newWidth, newHeight, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);

                using (Graphics gr = Graphics.FromImage(newBitmap))
                {
                    gr.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
                    gr.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
                    gr.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;
                    gr.DrawImage(layerBitmap, new Rectangle(0, 0, newWidth, newHeight));
                    gr.Dispose();

                }



           return newBitmap;

    }

   Bitmap newbitmap = createBigImage(bitmap, 9000, 9000);
```

Comment: http://www.asprangers.com/post/2012/03/23/Why-you-should-not-use-SystemDrawing-from-ASPNET-applications.aspx

Comment: The real issue is probably that the instance of `newbitmap` is not disposed. However in what sense would you need a `9000x9000` image? I'm sure whatever you're trying to do can be done better.

Comment: Should work reasonably fine in 64-bit process. Width of (9000*4byte-per-pixel) is not hitting 64K limit per line yet (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6333681/c-sharp-parameter-is-not-valid-creating-new-bitmap). Could you please confirm that your code runs in 64-bit process?

Comment: I got the same `Parameter is not valid` error when I ran your code passing in a JPG file as the `bitmap` parameter. Putting in the full path name solved it. Perhaps you should look at your inputs? The size didn't seem to be an issue (I tried 10000).

Comment: At what line do you get the error? Full exception with stack trace? It is unclear that the issue is the size of bitmap.. or if it is something else?

Comment: I am getting error in    Bitmap newBitmap = new Bitmap(newWidth, newHeight, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);                I can create 6000*6000 Image .

Comment: @sreejaya Are you calling createBigImage within a loop? I tried a quick test, and your method worked fine on its own. However, when I called it within a loop, it failed after 3 iterations. Calling `newbitmap.Dispose()` (as @Bauss suggested above) at the end of each loop eliminated the error. I'd guess it's a memory issue.

Comment: I tried this code without any loop and any other. I tried to call in page load itself and also tried different  machine. I cant able to create an Image . Always exception is coming "Parameter is not valid". I have to do any specific settings in asp.net ?

Comment: My windows : Window7 Enterprise  System Typ : 64 bit Os                             I tried in another system with 32 bit OS, that is working. Is it causing because of 64 bit OS ?