# Parameter is not valid - Trying to convert raw image to jpeg

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.5

I am trying to convert raw image file to .jpeg using below code:

```
byte[] bytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\TestFiles\input.NEF");
using (Image image = Image.FromStream(new MemoryStream(bytes)))
{
    image.Save(@"C:\TestFiles\output.jpeg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);
}
```

But fails with the message:

> Parameter is not valid.

I know it may be because low memory (from this question about [C# “Parameter is not valid.” creating new bitmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6333681/c-sharp-parameter-is-not-valid-creating-new-bitmap))  but I believe there is enough memory. The input .nef file is 11.1mb

[image]

Comment: `.NEF` files are not supported by .NET framework - download the SDK from Nikon

Comment: As @fubo has told you, you'll need a external library to open .Nef files, something like this http://sourceforge.net/p/nikoncswrapper/wiki/Home/

Comment: Image.FromStream does not know what a .NEF is... try convert it locally to a known format... PNG or BMP then try the same code. if it works it means that it didnt understand .NEF. and as other have said you will need to use a lib that understands .NEF