# While converting the image to bitmap I am getting parameter is not valid. How to resolve this issue.?

Tags: c#

The image i trying to convert into bitmap is of size 36.7 MB and having dimensions 
29696 x 4381.

I am posting my code below:

What I have tried:

```
try
{
    FileStream fs = new FileStream(FilePath,FileMode.Open,FileAccess.Read);

    System.Drawing.Image objImage = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(fs);//From File

    int height = objImage.Height;//Actual image width
    int width = objImage.Width;//Actual image height
    LineNumber = 1;
    System.Drawing.Bitmap bitmapimage = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(objImage, width, height);// create bitmap with same size of Actual image.Getting error on this line    
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
}
```

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IpXPx.png)

Comment: please see this answer (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6333681/c-sharp-parameter-is-not-valid-creating-new-bitmap). You are more then likely hitting the memory cap

Comment: Consider using WIC https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee719654%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: Could you please show as a whole code

Comment: I am a little bit confused. How the bitmap image can have size 36.7 MB if the image resolution is  29696 x 4381? I guess that you are using an ARGB bitmap that needs 32bit per pixel. Is it correct? The expected size is around 500MB

Comment: Probably a JPEG image.  Project > Properties > Build tab, untick the "Prefer 32-bit" checkbox.  You don't prefer it when you want to load such huge images.

Comment: @cristallo: Raw image file is 36.7 Mb. The Bitmap size is more than 500 mb

Comment: @HansPassant Prefer 32-bit is already unchecked

Comment: It is technically possible to run out of memory in a 64-bit process as well.  You are not calling the **required** Dispose() method to get rid of old bitmap objects.  You forgot it on the *objImage* object, probably in the rest of your program as well.  The GC cannot usually help, the Bitmap class is quite small.  Practice using the *using* statement.  Also, the `fs` variable is quite dangerous.  You cannot close the stream until the bitmap is disposed.  Your program will also fail if you try to load the same file again.

Comment: I think that your problem is the image format not the memory. Can you try to create an empty bit image using the desired size without loading the image itself? `bitmap=new Bitmap(newWidth,newHeight);`. It is a test for excluding memory issue.

Comment: @cristallo  i am able to create empty bitmap image

Comment: Can you try to load the image from stream con-validating the image data? `Image.FromStream(fs, false, true);`

Comment: @cristallo still giving the same error

Comment: Can you confirm that the error is still happening on line `new System.Drawing.Bitmap(objImage, width, height);`?

Comment: @cristallo ya it's on the same line