# C++/CLI Exception: "Parameter is not valid" constructing a Bitmap

Tags: .net, opencv, c++-cli

I'm trying to display a `cv::Mat` object (opencv) in Winform `PictureBox`:

```
void Show(cv::Mat& picture, PictureBox^ box) {
    cv::Mat pic;
    cv::resize(picture, pic, cv::Size(250, 250)); //picturebox size = 250, 250
    box->Image = gcnew System::Drawing::Bitmap(
        pic.cols, pic.rows, pic.step,
        System::Drawing::Imaging::PixelFormat::Format24bppRgb,
        (System::IntPtr)pic.data
    );
    box->Refresh();
}
```

The constructor of `Bitmap` throw exception: "Parameter is not valid". I found a similar problem from: [C# "Parameter is not valid." creating new bitmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6333681/c-sharp-parameter-is-not-valid-creating-new-bitmap)
It is answered that the `Bitmap` is comsuming too much space. However my `Bitmap` is only 250x250 or ~180kB of memory. I don't think 180kB is too much.

I tried reducing the picture size to 200x200 and it works. But that is too small for my need. And this proves that the problem must be the size of picture.

Comment: Just to be sure: Try to change the last parameter of `Bitmap` from `(System::IntPtr)pic.data` to `IntPtr(pic.data)`.

Comment: Try to set size divided on 4 or 8 or 16